# "News from him" vs "News about him"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-verbs

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

I have not heard any news **from** him.
I have not heard any news **about** him.

Answer (score 3):

Which one is "correct" depends on what you mean to say. The difference between them is nothing more than the difference between the prepositions "from" and "about."

> [**from**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/from#Preposition), preposition
> 1. *Used to indicate source or provenance.*
>
> > Paul is **from** New Zealand.
> > I got a letter **from** my brother.
> > You can't get all your news **from** the Internet.

> [**about**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/about#Preposition), preposition
> 4. Concerning; with regard to; on account of; on the subject of; to affect.
>
> > He talked a lot **about** his childhood.
> > We must do something **about** this problem.

So: If you mean to say that you have not heard *your brother tell you any news* then you say "I have not had any news **from** him." But if you mean that you have not heard *anyone else mention your brother* then you say "I have not had any news **about** him."

Comment: Yet, "about him" would naturally include news about the person from that person directly.